# How can we measure the variability in time-series power consumption patterns?

Tags: python, r, time-series, pattern-matching, entropy

Figure 1: X-axis represents the time (0-23 hours) and Y-axis represents the electricity consumption in kWh. I am working with time-series power consumption data. Figure 1 shows the shapes of one user on Wednesday, Thursday and Friday. All the shapes look different that indicates the stochastic behavior of that user. I want to measure this variability in load shapes. My ultimate goal is to quantify the difference in consumption patterns across days. What kind of statistical techniques I can use for the same? Is there any library/package available in python/R?
[image]

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you need recommendations for statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] or [datascience.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there. Asking for package recommendations is considered off topic. Instead focus on solving a particular problem and if a package is necessary, it will be included in the answer.

Comment: The `feasts` package in R can extract a wide variety of features from time series, including a few relevant ones like "spikiness." https://github.com/tidyverts/feasts